# node js mysql query result rendered to chart.js labels in pug page

Tags: mysql, node.js, chart.js, pug

I've this strange behaviour when i make a get request. A query to mysql calls for totals of sells(float) group by days (nvarchar). I've made 2 arrays (for totals and datas) where i push the content of the result

```
router.get('/movmensili', function(req, res ,next){
 if(!req.session.user){
 return res.redirect('/'); 
} 
executeQuery("SELECT SUM(price) as Totale, Data FROM db10101.10101 group by Data order 
by Data", function(error, resmov){
    
    var dateArray = [];
    var totaliArray = [] ;
    for (var i = 0; i<resmov.length; i++) {
        dateArray.push(resmov[i].Data)   
    }
    for (var i = 0; i<resmov.length; i++) {
        totaliArray.push(resmov[i].Totale)   
    }
    
    res.render('movmensili', {title: 'movs', date: (dateArray), totali: totaliArray
    });
   });   
});

console.log(dateArray); //['2022-05-01','2022-05-02','2022-05-03','2022-05-04','2022-05-05']
console.log(totaliArray); //[ '4.00', '5.50', '3.00', '1.75', null ]
```

so far so good
once I open my Pug page i got to draw a bar chart with Chart.js
the two arrays used for the chart axes, contains numeric values, no problems for the sell totals, but the xlabels should be strings. So far the xlabes are 2016(=2022 minus 05 minus 01), 2015, 2014 and so on....

```
canvas#myChart(style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 10 auto')
 script.
    const xlabels = [#{date}]  //[2022-05-01,2022-05-02,2022-05-03,2022-05-04,2022-05-05]
    
    const ydatas = [#{totali}] //[4.00,5.50,3.00,1.75,]
```

I wasn't able to convert / cast / stringify the x values to get the result needed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: David: it looks like the x-axis values are date strings.  Was that your intent?

Comment: the problem is actually that are not Strings but numbers. when displayed on the chart as labels for the X axis i got the results  of a numeric expression  2022 - 05 - 01 = 2016....  2015 for may the 2nd , 2014 for may the 3rd.  The array should look like   ['2022-05-01','2022-05-02','2022-05-03','2022-05-04','2022-05-05'], in this format the labels are populated correctly,  but in fact apexes are missing

Answer (score 0):

David, this worked for me.  Are you sure you are passing the labels correctly on render (try date: dateArray instead of date: (dateArray)). I didn't create a render function for this page so hard coded the labels and data arrays:

```
        script.
            var labels = ['2022-05-01','2022-05-02','2022-05-03','2022-05-04','2022-05-05',]
            var data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: ['4.00', '5.50', '3.00', '1.75', null],
                }]
            };
            var config = {type: 'line',data: data,options: {}};
            var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"),config);
```

Comment: if I hardcode the labels in       const xlabels = [#{date}], instade of importing from page render, everything works fine. It' actually that the point. the console.log of dateArray

Comment: David: can you display the labels in a separate div as soon as you render the page to see how the dates are being send to the page.  Something like this: each date in dataArray div date

Answer (score 0):

if I hardcode the labels in:

```
const xlabels = [#{date}]
```

instead of importing from page render, everything works fine. It's exactly that the point. The `console.log` of `dateArray` is perfectly as I would like to be in the `xlabels`, while once imported the quotes disappear

```
console.log(dateArray); // ['2022-05-01','2022-05-02','2022-05-03','2022-05-04','2022-05-05']
const xlabels = [#{date}]; // [2022-05-01,2022-05-02,2022-05-03,2022-05-04,2022-05-05]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not best solution, but it works....
async function GetData()

```
        var xlabel = '#{date}';
        var xlabel = xlabel.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'); 
        alert(xlabel);
        var xlabel = xlabel.split(",");
        alert(xlabel);



        for(i = 0; i < xlabel.length; i += 1){
         xlabel[i] = xlabel[i];
         //alert(numarray[i]);
         xlabels.push(xlabel[i]);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).